# Cannot log in to phpMyAdmin with my root password for mySQL (on Mac OS X Lion)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, osx-lion

So I am trying to log in to phpMyAdmin using my root password (Username: root Password: ******), however, I continue to receive the error:

> #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I am pretty sure I know the root password, as I have typed into terminal on Mac OS X the line:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

and was prompted with a `"Password:"` line.  I typed the password, and the terminal read:

`Starting MySQL...SUCCESS!`  And thus the server started up.  I am not sure why the same password is not working for phpMyAdmin.

I have tried setting the password in terminal with the command:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password *******
```

But I receive the output:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I have tried several websites, and the MySQL instructions are useless on this matter. I particularly want to solve it on Mac OS X Lion.

### Update

I've been trying to reset the root password, and have been following these instructions: http://www.coolestguyplanet.net/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/

However, when I use the command:  /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

I receive the following output:

```
111217 10:00:42 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/******-********-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
111217 10:00:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 107: /usr/local/mysql/data/********-********-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/*******-**********-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
111217 10:00:42 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/*********-********-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 107: /usr/local/mysql/data/*******-*********-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
**********-*********-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$
```

Why would my permission be denied?

Comment: Can you connect to the `mysql` command line client using the root password?

Answer (score 45):

In `config.inc.php` change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` key.

Comment: After upgrading from OSX Lion to Mountain Lion, I had to reinstall mysql. After, phpMyAdmin would not log in anymore. I tried adding mcrypt support, which didn't fix it.

I came across this answer and it fixed it!

What I did was: download the newest phpMyAdmin, browse to the source folder, copy the existing file config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php, and then change the localhost line to 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

Comment: Thank you for this.  Sometimes the solution is so simple.

Comment: Yep, this fixed it for me! Rob Ganly

Comment: searched for almost an hour and that simple change helped me !

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/)

Make sure your password is correct, if you need it you can change it with this

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password
```

When it asks for a password, do not enter anything, just hit enter. It will then ask you to enter new password, then confirm. Finished.

Then you will need also to do this.

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: This answer worked perfect for me, wonder why it only has 4 upvotes when creating a symbolic link for the mysql socket is one of the things that needs to be done?

Comment: you are a god mr delkant

Answer (score 7):

1. Change `phpMyAdmin/config.sample.inc.php`  to `phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`;
2. In `config.inc.php`,  change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`;
3. There is another `config.inc.php` in `phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/config.inc.php`, please ignore it.

Comment: changing **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** solved the issue for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Hey I had this problem but I fixed this.
I just created a new user for mysql and then you can just login to your phpmyadmin.

Do the following things:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then enter your password:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'enter your password just right here';
```

and set the all permissions for your new user.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

and then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When it says `(using password: NO)` it means that it isn't receiving a password.

Use `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p *******`

Comment: when I use this command, I receive:  

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is:

Set / change / reset the MySQL root password on Ubuntu Linux. Enter the following lines in your terminal.

Stop the MySQL Server.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Start the mysqld configuration.

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

Login to MySQL as root.

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

hope this help someoneelse..it worked for me!!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Sepp's answer, I would also like to point out that if you have set MySQL port to another port (i.e. 3307) , you can append the port number like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';
```

to the `config.inc.php` file

I hope anyone who used a different port number can benefit from my answer

Answer (score 0):

And check this mysql config file -

`[mysqld]
default_password_lifetime=0`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html