# Cannot connect to PhpMyAdmin using root (XAMPP)

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I can't log in my PhpMyAdmin using root, but I can when I use an other user.

I don't understand why, I tried a lot of stuff but none of them work

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

When I try to change the 'auth_type' to config I cannot connect to PhpMyAdmin at all!

W7 32 bits, xampp 5.6.21

Comment: Do you get a specific error? Have you tried replacing 127.0.0.1 with 'localhost'?

Comment: Hello and thanks !

 it say  "Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

Yes I tried to change 127.0.0.1 by localhost and I have the same problem

Comment: Did you set at password for the root mysql user? Or perhaps forget what the password is?  Try setting/resetting the root password using the instructions @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html and let us know if you still have an issue.

Comment: hello 

i still have the same message....

Comment: Hmmmmm, not sure but you could check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546669/cannot-log-in-to-phpmyadmin-with-my-root-password-for-mysql-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: It's possible that the XAMPP package is over-writing your values of user and password. One way they might do that is to change information in `libraries/vendor_config.php`, though there are several other methods they might use too, including hardcoding the values directly in the code. What I would do if it were me is to install my own phpMyAdmin in to the web root folder, using a different name, which will bypass any modifications the XAMPP folks have made. Then you can see if you still have the problem. See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install for details.